# SharePoint 2016 installation error on standalone server

Tags: 2016

I get below errors when I run the SharePoint 2016 configuration wizard in single server deployment and sql server also inside same server this is development environment

Resource id to be retrieved is PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog for language English (United States)
10/24/2016 10:37:38  12  INF                            Resource retrieved id PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog is Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.

Entering function TaskDriver.OnTaskDriverStop
10/24/2016 10:37:38  12  INF
Sending a task driver stop event: TaskDriverEventArgs.EventCriticalityType error, TaskDriverEventArgs.EventType.stop,

[image]

### UPDATE

Appfaric cache service still in problem.

Error while installing AppFabric:

> AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server -- Error 1722. There is a problem
>   with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the
>   setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or
>   package vendor.  Action Env_PSModulePath_powershell_i, location:
>   c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.exe, command:
>   powershell.exe "-command \"$str =
>   [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable(\\"PSModulePath\\",
>   [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine); $str =
>   $str+\\";c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\PowershellModules\\";  c:\Windows\system32\setx.exe /M
>   PSModulePath \\"$str\\"\""
>   "C:\Users\spinstall\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2016-10-24
>   20-03-00).log"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below steps:

**1. Repair distributed cache**

Tried to repair distributed cache on the server by executing the following line of PowerShell script

```
Get-SPServiceInstance
$s = Get-SPServiceInstance <<Distributed Cache GUID>>
$s.delete()
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

For some reasons, the script throws following error on line Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance

> Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance : Could not load file or
>   assemblly 'Microsoft. ApplicationServer.Caching.Configuration,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

**2. Start AppFabric Caching Service**

Started AppFabric Caching Service and add the SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance 
[image]

**3. Install CU7 for AppFabric 1.1**

Since running the configuration wizard again failed, downloaded and Installed Cumulative Update 7 (KB3092423) for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server

**NOTE:** If you get error in installation of AppFabric then check for **PSModulePath** environment variable value. It may contain `"` at the end of the value. Please remove the `"` from the end and try to install it again.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3092423

**4. Reboot**

Restart the computer after applying this cumulative update package.

**5. PS Script**

After successfully installing the CU package. Execute the following PowerShell script to remove the caching service instance.

```
$SPFarm = Get-SPFarm
 $cacheClusterName = "SPDistributedCacheCluster_" + $SPFarm.Id.ToString()
 $cacheClusterManager = [Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.Utilities.SPDistributedCacheClusterInfoManager]::Local
 $cacheClusterInfo = $cacheClusterManager.GetSPDistributedCacheClusterInfo($cacheClusterName);
 $instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
 $serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.Service.Tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.Server.Name) -eq $env:computername}
 $serviceInstance.Delete()
```

[image]

**6. Run the Configuration Wizard again**

The configuration should be  successful.

**Reference:**

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34617.sharepoint-2016-troubleshooting-configuration-wizard-failed-with-error-cachehostinfo-is-null.aspx
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2014/11/01/appfabric-1-1-error-in-sharepoint-server-2013-installation/#comment-4485

Comment: Hi when did step 2 i did not found  AppFabric Caching Service in services.msc? please help

Comment: If your SharePoint prerequisites are installed properly, then you can see this service. Please check for SharePoint prerequisites installation before installing SharePoint.

Comment: i enable internet in this server and installed prerequisites and now can i uninstall  sharepoint and install again?

Comment: You can uninstall SharePoint from Start Menu -> Control Panel -> uninstall a program.

Comment: same issue after i uninstall and install and i did not found app fabric service in services list

Comment: there is appfabric errors please above for this error, i can not install appfaric

Comment: he PSModulePath environment variable is corrupted. There is a quotation mark at the end from where to delete the quotation mark https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2014/11/01/appfabric-1-1-error-in-sharepoint-server-2013-installation/#comment-4485

Comment: Yes. Please remove (") from the end of that environment variable. After that Appfabric will be installed successfully.

Comment: hi appfabric installed but when i run configuration wizard again failed and found below errors Resource id to be retrieved is PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog for language English (United States)
Resource retrieved id PostSetupConfigurationFailedEventLog is Configuration of SharePoint Products failed.

Entering function TaskDriver.OnTaskDriverStop
Sending a task driver stop event: 

TaskDriverEventArgs.EventCriticalityType error, TaskDriverEventArgs.EventType.stop, Configuration of SharePoint Products 

failed.  Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products

Comment: i run above commands to delete distributed cache, Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance and started the appfarbric service started

Comment: but and configuration wizard run successfully but after i got below errors in event viewr Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=local doesn't exist in the directory.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)

Answer (score 0):

after i remove " from PSModulePath environment variable and  Repair distributed cache it works for me